# How can I print variables in a specific sharable?

Tags: gdb

To simplify things, let's say I have the following in xxx.c:

```
int foo = 0;

void bar() {
   ...
}
```

Conditional compilation inside bar let's me compile in two ways. I compile using the first way, and create a shared library, let's call it lib1.so. Then I compile using the second way, and create another shared library, let's call it lib2.so. Now I run my main program, and I dynamically load (dlopen) both lib1.so and lib2.so. If I ask gdb to "print foo", it will print out a value, but which one is it? I can't qualify foo with a filename ('xxx.c'::foo) because the source name is the same for both sharables. Is there a way to tell gdb to specifically print foo from lib1.so, or foo from lib2.so?

If I set a breakpoint on 'bar', gdb is smart enough to set 2 breakpoints, one in each shareable. So I am a little surprised that "print foo" does not similarly print two values, one for each shareable.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard "sharable" to mean a "shared library" in 30 years of doing programming. You appear to have invented this term, which is ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print variables in a specific sharable?

I don't believe there is currently a way to do that. [This bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13590) is relevant.

Note: if you have *external* variable (that is, you didn't use any special flags, such as `-fvisibility-hidden` or a linker script to mark `foo` hidden), then *all* references to `foo` will bind to whichever library was `dlopen`ed first, so  only *one* instance of `foo` will be used from either instance of `bar` (this is one major difference between how UNIX shared libraries and Windows DLLs work).

You could of course look up the other instance via `dlsym(..., "foo")`.